# MYSQL query won't show results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I keep getting an empty result set back from my query when it should not be.
Here is my first table- person

```
1   u_id    bigint(20) 
2   first   varchar(15)                     
3   last    varchar(15)
```

second table- test

```
1   u_id    bigint(20)          
2   score   smallint(6)
```

Query I'm using-

```
SELECT score
FROM person, test
WHERE last ='Roberts'   ;
```

It works if I use a query-

```
SELECT score
FROM person, test
WHERE first ='Tim'  ;
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have any records with `Roberts` for the last name? Note tha tsince you're doing equality tests, even something like `Roberts[space]` will fail to match.

Comment: Yes the records are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the following query:

```
SELECT score 
FROM person p
INNER JOIN test t ON p.u_id = t.u_id
WHERE Trim(p.last) ='Roberts'
```

and:

```
SELECT score 
FROM person p
INNER JOIN test t ON p.u_id = t.u_id
WHERE Trim(p.first) ='Tim'
```